# Activating another country's key on Steam in United States, any problems?

Tags: steam

I just bought a game from Greenmangaming and got a Steam key. However, when I went to activate it on Steam it said I activated the UK version of the game. I live in the US and want to know if there will be any problems playing it and which version of the game will be installed.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I doubt you will have any problems. The only problems you might have is if you tried to purchase a game (on steam) in another currency to make it cheaper for yourself and *then* played the game in a different country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is in the [Steam Region Restrictions FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1266-QFZC-2141)

However, said answer is anything but clear.  Basically, for CD Keys (which these would count as), it says

> Region restrictions on CD Keys vary by each individual publisher. There is no standard or universal restriction placed on retail games.

Having said that, I haven't had any problems activating keys from GmG in the past.  Granted, this was only three titles: Murdered: Soul Suspect, Alien: Isolation, and the Alien Isolation Season Pass.

You'll know if the key was rejected, as it'd tell you so when you try to activate it.